# WPF Remove Window Body (Title Bar Only)

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to create a music player, and I wanted to have a "minimalist mode" where it collapses into a compact row of controls, much like WinAmp's [docked mode](http://www.getwinamp.net/mirror/website/AOLCDN_C/WINAMP/WINAMP_WINDOWSHADE_MODE.JPG).

I was hoping to use MahApps.Metro to accomplish this, since it allows for controls in the title bar. However, WPF doesn't seem to allow a window body to be smaller than 8 px tall, so setting the window size to 28 (the height of the title bar) results in this weird [8-px-tall piece of the window body hanging off the bottom of the title bar](http://image.prntscr.com/image/0af2e242359e40649027f2d76e51fd5e.png) once the window is moved.

Also, setting WindowStyle to None isn't doable since that isn't supported by MahApps.Metro, which I would like to use when the window is in "normal mode".

Is there any way to *completely* hide the body of a WPF window so that only the title bar is showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can totally reproduce your Issue with the Metro-Samples.

I did a Qick-fix to make it look like [image: this]

Now it has no more pixels below the Titlebar.

**What did i do?**

To be honest it's more a workaround than a proper solution, but you can simply set `TitlebarHeight="39"`

Hope this fits your needs

Comment: It's a good enough workaround for now, but 39 pixels isn't all too compact.

Comment: I agree with you. The only proper solution for you might be to download the sources and modify them. But on the other hand, 39px can be a bit tiny too if you want to have an ergonomic look and feel

Comment: It could be, but the compact mode would be toggle-able. I think I'll just have to _really_ shrink the default tile bar height. Even then, WPF's minimum window height might be overall, rather than excluding the title bar. In that case, reducing the default height from 32 to 24 would mean I have 16 px off the bottom instead of 8 px.